# How to notify user if ASP.NET MVC Code Error?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a code like this:

```
public IActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    var classT = db.ClassTables.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Id == id);
    db.ClassTables.Remove(classT);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

In this code, I want to notify the user that "an error has occurred" if an error occurs in the DB. How can I do that?

Comment: Use a Try Catch and in the Catch redirect to an error page with the wanted message.

Comment: I believe that this article [Exception Handling in ASP.NET MVC](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/exception-handling-in-mvc) is what you need.